# Custom hook to execute an axios request [React, Typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to create a reusable custom hook (useRequest) where I can fetch data with axios, display it and have a loading state. In case of an error I want it to be caught by useRequest.
I'm having trouble catching eventual errors and passing the axios request to useRequest.
Currently I'm only getting null for the error message.

EDIT: I use generated api which uses axios. So to make my fetch request it would look something like this:

```
import {GeneratedApi} from '/generatedApi'

const generatedApi = new GeneratedApi(configuration) //configuration is for editing the headers etc.
const response = await generatedApi.getData();
setData(response.data);
```

My code:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useRequest = (promise: Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setError(null);
        await promise;
        setLoading(false);
        setError(null);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        setError("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [promise]);

  return [loading, error];
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any | null>(null);

  const [loading, error] = useRequest(async () => {

    const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    setData(response.data);
    return response;
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  } else if (data) {
    return <p>{data}</p>;
  } else {
    return <p>Error: {error}</p>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to reference this: https://swr.vercel.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konstantin Samarin's answer helped to point me in the right direction.

My current solution has a missing dependency(callback) and might not be ideal. Adding the dependency causes infinite rerenders.

EDIT 1: Added isMounted reference to avoid setting state on an unmounted component. Moved [data, setData] to the custom hook.

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface RequestReponse {
    loading: boolean,
    error: string | null
}

function useRequest<T>(callback: any, dependencies: any[]): [boolean, (string | null), (T | null)] {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;

        async function doRequest() {
            try {
                setError(null);
                setData(null);
                await callback();
                if (isMounted) {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setData(null);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setLoading(false);
                setError(error)
            }
        }

        doRequest();
        return () => {
             isMounted = false;
        };
    }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    return [loading, error, data];
}

export default function App() {

  const generatedApi = new GeneratedApi();

  const [loading, error, data] = useRequest(() => generatedApi.getData(), [])

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  } else if (data) {
    return <p>{data}</p>;
  } else {
    return <p>Error: {error}</p>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function, wrapped in useCallback hook, which would invoke your api call:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"

const useRequest = (apiCall: () => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>, setData: (data: any) => void) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setError(null);
        const response = await apiCall()
        setData(response.data)
        setLoading(false);
        setError(null);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        setData(null)
        setError("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [apiCall, setData]);

  return [loading, error];
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any | null>(null);
  const fun = useCallback(() => axios.get(url), [])

  const [loading, error] = useRequest(fun, setData);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  } else if (data) {
    return <p>{'data'}</p>;
  } else {
    return <p>Error: {error}</p>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly when I open your link I only get the default Codesandbox project.
 
If you move the complete logic to useRequest then I would only be able to make that specific axios call right? What I actually want is to be able to reuse useRequest with different axios calls (actually generated by OpenApi). Sorry if I'm missing the point, quite new to programming.

Comment: You could also pass an additional parameter using which useRequest would differentiate the type of axios call.

Comment: Sorry I should probably have made it more clear that I am actually using a generated api which uses axios calls. Which in that case means I don't have a specific url I can use. I'll edit the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Ok, I got it. What about this? Check the updated answer.

Comment: Your answer helped point me in a working direction. Thank you :) I posted my current solution as a comment and will update it if I find a better solution.